# WordPress plugin, display registration page, on button click

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have created a registration plugin in WordPress and I want to display my register-employee.php(under view folder) file. When a user click on a button(used that url to display the file, something like that). Below is my folder structure hope would help.

```
>controller
>model
>public
>view
 register-employee.php
register-member.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altough your description is very little,
I give you a really simple guide on how to do this:

First thing, opening a form on click is a javascript thing so the first thing you need to do is add your JavaScript file,

let's assume you have a file `assets/js/register.js` which looks like this:

```
var btn = document.querySelector('button.my-register-button');
btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.querySelector('#my_registration_popup').style.display = 'block';
});
```

Then we need to add this file to `wp_enqueue_scripts` action in order to be added to Wordpress pages

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
   wp_register_script('my-registration-plugin', YOUR_PLUGIN_URL . '/assets/js/register.js', [], null, true);
});
```

assuming that your register-employee.php file looks something like this:

```
<div id="my_registration_popup" style="display: none">
   <!-- my form -->
</div>
```

First thing you need to do is to add above view to `wp_footer` action:

```
add_action('wp_footer', function() {
  include PATH_TO_YOUR_PLUGIN . '/view/register-employee.php';
});
```